# Prevent prior executions of the useEffect from updating state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, async-await

I'm purposely keeping this example abstract.

**Situation:**
My React useEffect hosts an async function that will make a call to an async function.
The situation I'm facing is that the useEffect will begin executing, while it's executing the useEffect will start executing a second time (this is desired behavior due to the dependency array). Due to a conditional statement, the second iteration doesn't need to make such a time intensive async call, so it finishes first and updates state with the data. Later, the original execution finishes and overrides the state with its data.

**Issue:**
How do I prevent prior executions of the useEffect from updating state and only allow the most current execution to update state?

Example code of the useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
     let data = [];
     try {
       if (xyz) {
         data = await lessTimeIntensive();
       } else {
         data = await moreTimeIntensive();
       }
       setResponse(data);
     }
   })();
}, [value1, value2, value3]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation is handled by `useEffect`'s clean-up function:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // do things

  return () => {
    // cleanup
  }
})
```

A common pattern looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let cancelled = false;
  getData().then((data) => {
    if (!cancelled)
       setData(data);
  }); 
  return () => {
    cancelled = true;
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! I was aware of the cleanup method, but never needed to use it and I suppose I never understood the purpose of it till now!